# Program to automatically send email works perfectly according to IDLE, but the email is never received

Tags: python, ssl, smtplib

I've been making a program in python to work towards sending emails automatically. It should be quite simple.

I've tried multiple different methods and after an hour of experimenting with new and unfarmiliar modules I have finally come to the code that I have now.

```
import smtplib, ssl
port = 587
server_name = 'smtp.gmail.com'
email = 'not_telling_you@my_email.com'
recipient = 'not_telling_you1@my_email.com'
message = 'Hello world'
context = ssl.create_default_context()
print('Having trouble? Go to "accounts.google.com > settings > less secure             app access > turn on access > on" when using a gmail account. It is not     recommended to do this with your normal account.')

import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Log in"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.login
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                          command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def login(self):
        server = smtplib.SMTP(server_name, port)
        print('Connecting to server...')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        print('Successfully connected to', server_name, 'through port', port)
        print('Logging in...')
        server.login(email,'****************')
        print('Successfully logged into', email)
        server.sendmail(email, recipient, message)
        print('Successfully sent', message, 'from', email, 'to', recipient)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

It should simply send the email automatically when the user clicks login (I haven't bothered to change what it says, I'm building off of a bit of an older program). It gets to the sent box of the sender email,but the recipient never receives the email.

Comment: You should implement logging into your code. This will help examine the sequence of execution and any problems whatsoever. The recipient may check the Junk/Spam folder in their mailbox or other email settings to allow emails from this particular email address/domain.

Comment: Your `message` is also not a valid mail message which should consist of a header with From, To, Subject ... and a body. It is not unlikely that such bad mails get silently discarded - specifically outlook/hotmail/live.com is known for accepting mail which looks bad or looks like spam but then discarding it. Gmail instead usually reject mails if they don't like it but even if accepted they might automatically end up in the spam folder of the recipient.